# How do I solve a MySQL syntax error exception?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to insert data into my jtable from wampserver mysql database. I keep on getting this specific error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe près de ')' à la ligne 1.`

Here is my code

```
public Boolean add( String Registration,String Departure, String capacity, String Date, String Destination, String Startpoint) {
    //SQL STATEMENT
    String sql = "INSERT INTO travel_schedule( Registrationno,Capacity, Date, Destination,Departuretime,Startpoint) VALUES('"+Registration+"', '"+ capacity + "','" + Date + "','" + Destination + "','" + Departure + "','" + Startpoint + "',)";
    try {
        //GET CONNECTION
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, username, password);

        //PREPARED STATEMENT
        Statement s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        s.execute(sql);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you do have a `,` before you close the `Values(...)`, which might be the cause of your exception.

Comment: Thanks Kevin Esche, i have removed the comma... had'nt seen that. However, the exeption is still there, just cant find it

Comment: You should be using a PreparedStatement instead of all this string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks again. solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the extra `'`, you have to remove both the `comma` and `'`

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO travel_schedule( Registrationno,Capacity, Date, Destination,Departuretime,Startpoint) VALUES("+ Registration +"','"+ capacity + "','" + Date + "','" + Destination + "','" + Departure
+ "','" + Startpoint + ")";
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Its running fine now

Answer (score 1):

In your sql query, Remove space after comma here  `Registration+"', '"+` and write it as `Registration+"','"+`  also
Remove comma here `Startpoint + "',)";`

use the below statement,

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO travel_schedule(Registrationno,Capacity,Date,Destination,Departuretime,Startpoint) VALUES('"+Registration+"','"+capacity+"','"+Date+"','"+ Destination +"','"+Departure+"','" +Startpoint+"')";
```

Comment: Thanks. Its running fine now